# Are there examples of different knots with identical Jones polynomials and different Seifert Genus?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, knot-theory, low-dimensional-topology, knot-invariants

I'm wondering if its ever possible to find two non-isotopic knots which have identical jones polynomials but different seifert genus?

Attempting to google for this I found [this](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1986-097-01/S0002-9939-1986-0831406-7/S0002-9939-1986-0831406-7.pdf) example of non-isotopic knots with identical jones polynomials. But in the first page of the paper its clearly stated that all the knots have identical genus.

Comment: This has been asked here where indeed a counter example was found: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/456521/are-there-examples-of-different-knots-with-identical-jones-polynomials-and-diffe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Conway knot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_knot?wprov=sfti1) and [Kinoshita-Teraska knot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinoshita%E2%80%93Terasaka_knot?wprov=sfti1) are mutants, so they share the same Jones polynomial. But the Conway knot has genus 3 and the Kinoshita-Terasaka knot has genus 2.